# how to convert hexa to dec using delphi and hex to octal?

Tags: delphi

```
function HexToDec(Str: string): Integer;
var
i, M: Integer;
begin
Result:=0;
M:=1;
Str:=AnsiUpperCase(Str);
for i:=Length(Str) downto 1 do
begin
case Str[i] of
  '1'..'9': Result:=Result+(Ord(Str[i])-Ord('0'))*M;
  'A'..'F': Result:=Result+(Ord(Str[i])-Ord('A')+10)*M;
end;
M:=M shl 4;
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
if Edit1.Text<>'' then
Label2.Caption:=IntToStr(HexToDec(Edit1.Text));
end;
```

How to using it without function, because i want to call the result again in other line, and how about hexa to octal  ? am i must conver from hexa to dec and then dec to octal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delphi can do this already, so you don't need to write a function parsing the number. It is quite simple, actually:

```
function HexToDec(const Str: string): Integer;
begin
  if (Str <> '') and ((Str[1] = '-') or (Str[1] = '+')) then
    Result := StrToInt(Str[1] + '$' + Copy(Str, 2, MaxInt))
  else
    Result := StrToInt('$' + Str);
end;
```

Note that that also handles negative hex numbers, or numbers like `+$1234`.

> How to using it without function, because i want to call the result again in other line ?

If you want to re-use the value, assign the result of `HexToDec` to a variable and use that in `IntToStr`.

---

FWIW, in your function, there is no need to call `AnsiUpperCase`, because all hex digits fall in the ASCII range anyway. A much simpler `UpperCase` should work too.

Comment: Kinda frustrating that his involves a heap allocation. Is there an RTL function that can avoid that?

Comment: @David: not an RTL function I can think of. But is it that much of a deal?

Comment: It could be a big deal in some situations. Usually not I agree.

Comment: The only way to avoid a heap allocation would be an improved version of OP‘s function, i.e. one that parses and does a shift-and-add for each hex digit. If a situation required top speed, I would write one, otherwise I would use ˋStrToIntˋ.

Comment: I recently wrote my own `IntToStr` and `FloatToStr` type methods to work with fixed length character arrays. This is for my YAML emitting code. When creating large files full of numbers this made a huge improvement to performance. It's a shame that the RTL doesn't have these capabilities.

Comment: how about hexa to octal ? am i must conver from hexa to dec and then dec to octal?

Comment: @Stefan: The function `HexToDec` is in fact a `HexToInt`, converting a hex string to an integer. Your conversion to octal is a conversion to a string again. You could do it from string to string directly, but I would rather convert hex to integer and then from there to any base you want.

Comment: @David: I have written such functions several times too, for e.g. my BigIntegers, BigDecimals, BigRationals and Decimals, but also for Integers and Int64s. If you need a function, it is always a shame if the RTL does not provide it. That's life. And I am still thinking of writing a generic FormatFloat-like function that takes a format string, a string of digits, an exponent, a sign and a decimal-places value, that would be able to format all kinds of numbers, e.g. from BigDecimal, BCD, the IEEE float types, BigRational, etc.

Answer (score 2):

My first comment would be that you are not converting hex to decimal with your function (although you are converting to decimal as an intermediate) but rather hex to integer. IntToStr then converts integer to base 10, effectively. To generalise what you want then I would create two functions - strBaseToInt and IntToStrBase where Base is meant to imply e.g. 16 for hex, 10 for dec, 8 for octal, etc., and assuming the convention adopted by hex that A=10, and so on but to (possibly) Z = 35 making the maximum base possible 36.

I don't handle + or - but that could be added easily.

In the reverse funtion, again for simplicity of illustration I have ommitted supporting negative values.

### Edit

Thanks to Rudy for this improvement

### Edit 2 - Overflow test added, as per comments

```
function StrBaseToInt(const Str: string; const Base : integer): Integer;
var
  i, iVal, iTest: Longword;
begin
  if (Base > 36) or (Base < 2) then raise Exception.Create('Invalid Base');
  Result:=0;
  iTest := 0;
  for i:=1 to Length(Str) do
  begin
    case Str[i] of
      '0'..'9': iVal := (Ord(Str[i])-Ord('0'));
      'A'..'Z': iVal := (Ord(Str[i])-Ord('A')+10);
      'a'..'z': iVal := (Ord(Str[i])-Ord('a')+10);
      else raise Exception.Create( 'Illegal character found');
    end;
    if iVal < Base then
    begin
      Result:=Result * Base + iVal;
      if Result < iTest then  // overflow test!
      begin
        raise Exception.Create( 'Overflow occurred');
      end
      else
      begin
        iTest := Result;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      raise Exception.Create( 'Illegal character found');
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Then, for example your HexToOct function would look like this

```
function HexToOct( Value : string ) : string;
begin
  Result := IntToStrBase( StrBaseToInt( Value, 16), 8 );
end;
```

### Additional

A general function would be

```
function BaseToBase( const Value : string; const FromBase, ToBase : integer ) : string;
begin
  Result := IntToStrBase( StrBaseToInt( Value, FromBase ),ToBase );
end;
```

Comment: If you have a conversion for any base, then why stop at base 16? Your base is tested to be in the range 2..36, but you only code for base 2..16 (up to `'F'`).  And for a base 12, `'F'` would be illegal. You should check that too, i.e. that the digit <= Base.

Comment: Sorry @RudyVelthuis - typo. I commented that I did not check for illegal chars though, for simplicity of illustration, but I can add it if needed.

Comment: OK. I think it would make the function far more useful if it could really handle everything properly, even bad digits. I would first convert character to digit (0..base - 1) and then add that to the result. Oh, and I inserted a begin after the while in `IntToStrBase`, see edit.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis thanks - beat me to it with the missing begin :-). I am just checking the validation and will update post shortly.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis i have the edit1.text for the input and edit2.text for the result . what should i change?

Comment: @StefanAdrianus: change where? If you want to use this function, do something like: `myInt := StrToIntBase(Edit1.Text, 16); Edit2.Text := IntToStrBase(myInt, 8);`. The former line converts the hex string to an integer, the latter the integer to an octal string.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Value := Value div Base; you assigned the value but when i ran the program "value never used"

Comment: @StefanAdrianus There was a bug, now fixed.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Validation of chars added, as requested

Comment: @RudyVelthuis i have declared it why it showing " declaration expected" the result its not showing in my edit2.text

Comment: @Stefan: you asked a question as a comment. I can't see your code. If you really want to ask more, ask a new question, and post the code. Comments are not the right place for this.

Comment: @Dsm: DRY. I would do: `case Str[i] of '0'..'9': digit := Ord(Str[i]) - Ord('0'); 'A'..'F': digit := Ord(Str[i]) - Ord('A') + 10 ;... etc. else raise .... end {case}; if digit < Base then Result := Result * Base + digit else raise EConvertError.Create('....');`. No need for IsCharValidInBase, as that does the same as your other case statement.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis In Result := IntToStrBase( StrBaseToInt( Value, 8), 16 ); can i change Result to Edit2.Text so the result go to edit.text?

Comment: @StefanAdrianus dsm wrote this answer, not Rudy, so please address you questions to me. And the answer to your question is yes, you can, of course (except that I assume a typo that if you change result to Edit2.text the result will be put in Edit2.Text, not Edit.Text).

Comment: ohh thankyou @Dsm but after i changed it cant running , declaration needed, begin expected

Comment: @StefanAdrianus sounds like a silly. Show me your code.

Comment: @StefanAdrianus BTW made a silly myself. My HexToOct function was actually OctToHex! (Sorry) Fixed now.

Comment: The thing that bothers me about the `StrBaseToInt` function is that there is no overflow checking. For example, the hexadecimal string `fedcba9876543210` is acceptable to the function, but it actually overflows an integer.

Comment: @RonMaupin What started out as a guide for the OP seems to have evolved into a full blown implementation! However, so be it.